# Is there an anonymous ID in Actions on Google with Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Is there an anonymous ID in Actions on Google with Dialogflow that I can access using DialogFlow in Node.js?

I don't need to know the Google account of who is using the Action, but I do want to have a unique identifier so that the Action can know when they come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a possible option...

*(When working in DialogFlow in Node.js, most code is in a handler and the parameter is usually called `conv`. The following assumes that it is inside such a handler.)*

On every single call, check for an 'existing' id in the session data and the user storage:

```
var id = conv.data.MyId || conv.user.storage.MyId || '';

if(!id) {
  id = /* make a new Id for this user... a GUID or some other unique id */
  conv.user.storage.MyId = id;
}
```

Once I get the Id from storage or make a new one, it is critical to reassign it to `conv.data`, since `conv.user.storage` seems to be reliably provided only on the first call!

```
// IMPORTANT
conv.data.MyId = id;

/* use the Id as needed */
```

My code looks up the Id in a firebase database to get details from their last visit.

This seems to be working, but may not be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Google no longer provides one for you. You will have to generate one when a new user interacts with your webhook and store the generated id in their user storage object.

To identify a new user your just check if they already have an id in their user storage object. For generating the id you can use an library like uuid. https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Uuidv4 is probably the one that you need if you just need a unique id for simple identifications

Comment: Thanks, @Jordi. I'm now using uuidv4 as suggested, though I remove the '-' and prepend a letter to be able to use it as a firebase id!

Answer (score 0):

The original idea from Google was to leverage a field called userStorage, but this feature seems to be borked ATM.

userStorage Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data

Reddit thread regarding issues:
https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/d88z7e/userstorage_saga_continued/

Unless something has changed (I haven't checked on userStorage since I've been busy writing a fix around it) you may be out of luck without Account Linking. Feel free to try userStorage and keep me honest as they may have remedied the situation internally.

Alternatively, if all you need is an identifier or session for a single conversation you can leverage the conversationId which will be unique until the conversation ends.